# Devexpress : Express Printing System - Print contents of 2 cxgrid's

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe4

Actually, I never tried this but it's supposed to work judging from some comments I've read. I have two grids: One displays Hotel guests and the other one their former stays (Date from- date to, etc..). Now I would like to be able to print both contents as a single report.How do I add the linked contents of the second grid to my dxComponentPrinter1Link1 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IDE open your form.

1. Right click and choose ReportLinks on the TdxComponentPrinter
   object.
2. In the links editor window, instead of clicking the Add button, click the dropdown arrow next to the Add button. Choose Add Composition.

This creates a TdxCompositionReportLink object. There is an Items property which will hold all of the report links you want in the composite report. This will print out as a single report. I can't promise both reports will be on the same page though. I've never figured out how to do that.